# ASP.NET MVC 3: Dynamically Loading Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, razor

I want to extend an existing CMS system, and I'm trying to add "module" support.

My goal is to be able to apply a module by adding a marker within the database content it's self.

Example:

```
<p>
    My fun content that is located in a paragraph tag
</p>
[news:1234]
 <p>
    ... more fun content within a different paragraph tag
</p>
```

The above example is very ad hoc, but you get the picture. I'd like to be able to dynamically load a `news.cshtml` view and use the news feed ID of `1234`.

The problem with this is that the content from the Model is the last thing over the wire, so I'm not sure how to tell the `index.cshtml` view to swap out the marker for the `news.cshtml` partial.

Any direction will be appreciated.

### EDIT

I'd also be open to suggestions on how to parse the content in the controller before passing it to the view.

Comment: Its not Razor but I'm preety sure Spark View Engine allows for this by Parsing the View multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not into parsing the content for your markup, another way you could do it is to place an actual div for the content to be loaded into.

```
<div class="news" id="1234"></div>
```

Then on your page have some javascript (jQuery) which filled these divs with calls to the server.

```
$(function() {
  $('.news').each(function() {
    $.get('/CMS/LoadNews/' + $(this).attr('id')).appendTo($(this));
  }
}
```

^ just off the top of my head, haven't double checked it works.

In most cases I would prefer the server side parsing, but depending on what this content is and whether it needs to be there at page load, this could be useful.

Comment: +1 cuz I do like the concept, unfortunately I need the site to be compatible with NON-Javascript enabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom HtmlHelper extension that parses the content, calls Html.Action, updates the text with the result, and returns the content for display.